# Openfst fstcompose for transducing

Tags: openfst

Trying to run an FST which I compiled with an input FSA, but when I do there is no output.
As I searched, the only run command in openfst is fstcompose, so what I try to do is compose the fst with the inputs as fsa.

pronoun.fsm.txt

```
0   1   <s> <s>
1   0   <eps>   <eps>
0   2   </s>    </s>
2   0   <eps>   <eps>
0   3   <unk>   <unk>
3   0   <eps>   <eps>
0   4   a   a
4   5   l   l
5   6   l   l
6   0   +PRN    #
0
```

symbols.txt

```
<eps>   0
<s> 1
</s>    2
<unk>   3
a   4
l   5
+PRN    6
#   7
```

test.fsm.txt

```
0 1 a
1 2 l
2 3 l
3 4 +PRN
4
```

So I created pronoun.fsm.txt as FST

```
fstcompile --isymbols=symbols.txt --osymbols=symbols.txt pronoun.fsm.txt>pronoun.fst
```

Then, I created my inputs as an acceptor

```
fstcompile --isymbols=symbols.txt --acceptor=true test.fsm.txt>test.fst
```

Lastly, I composed both fsts, but the output is nothing.

```
fstcompose pronoun.fst test.fst|fstprint --isymbols=symbols.txt --osymbols=symbols.txt
```

Here is the deal, I want to run a string input to a transducer I created with fstcompose command. But the output is blank.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the problem. I want to answer this question instead of deleting it because OpenFST has really insufficient documentation and this question answers how to run FST on OpenFST. The problem is on fstcompose you have to give your inputs as the first argument. So the solution is

```
fstcompose test.fst pronoun.fst |fstprint --isymbols=symbols.txt --osymbols=symbols.txt
```